# Date calculation: count days matching complex condition in given range w/o looping

Tags: algorithm, date

I'm implementing a small calendar app with recurrent events.
Event is specified using crontab syntax.

Expressions can be quite complex:

```
  00 11 28-31 */3 MON#1,MON#2,MONL */2
  ^  ^    ^    ^       ^            ^
  |  |    |    |       |            |
  |  |    |    |       |            * - every even year
  |  |    |    |       * - on first, second and last Monday of month
  |  |    |    * - every third month
  |  |    * - since 28th till 31st days of month
  |  * - at 11AM
  * - first minute of the hour
```

While preparing reports I need to count how many times given recurring event is being triggered. For now I'm using dead simple approach: just iterate through all dates in range and check if condition matches, but that seems to be super inefficient.

So my question is: can I somehow calculate the amount of days matching given conditions w/o looping through the range?

Thanks.

P.S. I've been googling a lot on that one and didn't find at least one implementation w/o loops. Is that something from NP kingdom?